# PHP: Get date by day name in given date range

Tags: php, datetime

I have two date range between  **2015-05-05** TO **2015-06-05(Y-m-d)** and also I have day array like

```
Array ( [0] => Sun [1] => Mon [2] => Tue )
```

So I want to return date between above date range of given day name only.

Your suggestion is valuable.

Thanks.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-diff.php

Answer (score -1):

To get the value between two dates, you can use [DateTime::diff](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php).

To return only day's name, you can use [DateTime::format](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) passing the parameter "l".

Others questions like that, you can find the answer on the doc. It's your friend! =P